# Should I use import jQuery in a script if jQuery is being added manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I am maintaining an existing project, and I saw this:

The site is already including jQuery the traditional way (it's WordPress, and WordPress includes jQuery by default unless you change stuff).

```
<script src="cdn-or-local/jquery.js"></script>
```

And then the site is including another javascript file, which has been compiled with Webpack and Babel.

```
<script src="wordpress-theme/dist/whatever.js"></script>
```

On the original whatever.js file (not the compiled one, but the human-created one), it states:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$(document).ready(() => {
...
}
```

And this confused me a lot.

As far as I know, if jQuery is already being loaded before the whatever.js file is loaded, then $ will already be defined.

**Question**: can I just safely omit `import $ from 'jquery';`?

Comment: You could do a [conditional import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only). That way, your module will always have what it needs.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Conditioned on what? Also that would make the module asynchronous, and complicate everything.

Comment: @Bergi - OP's presumption is that `$` is available globally as it is the `src` of a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Be careful not to have conflicting versions of jquery in your project.  This can be the source of difficult-to-fix errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a good practice to import jQuery if your module needs jQuery - explicit declarations are good for readability, and will allow tooling to know what `$` refers to! However, you can (should) [configure webpack to not bundle jQuery as a dependency, but assume it is already loaded and available from a global variable](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

Comment: Thanks, this completely answers my original question.